# How to find infrequently visited confluence pages?

Tags: confluence

How to find infrequently visited confluence pages?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best thing to do is set up Google Analytics on your Confluence installation (you can do this even if your installation is internal/intranet).

Simply register a new GA site profile, copy the GA script and paste it into the "At the end of Body" section of the **Custom HTML** Confluence admin backend function (you'll have to be a Confluence admin of course)

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://davidsimpson.me/2009/03/18/tracking-atlassian-confluence-usage-with-google-analytics/) by David Simpson.

NOTE: Because our company's Confluence installation is internal, the domain name of a rendered Confluence page didn't match the site profile's, so I had to use [this trick](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#domainToNone) to get the GA script to track correctly.

If you are behind a corporate firewall and haven't configured Confluence to deal with issues relating to this, [this page](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/CGAP/Occasionally+Asked+Questions) might be useful.

[David's plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/16722) will allow you to pull data from GA via the API and display it on pages in your own Confluence space (firewall issues notwithstanding) if you want.

After a period of time you should be able to use the data to find the quiet pages!

Answer (score 1):

**Install the [Archiving Plugin for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/123)**.

The plugin **tracks the last view date of each page**, and allows you to configure an automatic report to find the pages not viewed by anyone in the last N days. You can configure the feature and the value of *N* at space level.

[Learn more](http://midori.hu/products/confluence-archiving-plugin/documentation/view-tracking)